# Get Json document data from online file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

As I am new with json can you guys please help me out? My data file is at this url - http://www.thedailystar.net/json/category
Now I want to show it in the following format:

```
<ul id="smenu">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

So, how can I get the request to get data from the url and run a loop to print it out? I have tried this code but nothing happened. Thanks in advance :)

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.thedailystar.net/json/category";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<li href="' + arr[i].name + '">' +
            arr[i].display + '</li><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("smenu").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: are you using `www` in address on the page? If not it is cross domain request. Use browser dev tools network tab to inspect request. If you aren't working on `thedailystar.net` domain it will definitely be corss domain and subject to `same origin policy`

Comment: thanks for the reply . Yes while i done your responded step i found the cross domain origin policy . And i am on different server. What can i do now to get the access of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JavaScript is not running on thedailystar.net domain it will be a cross domain request. If this is the case, you will need to enable CORS on your resource server (http://www.thedailystar.net/json/category).

Most of the time, to enable CORS, the server needs to return the following header in its response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

More information on CORS: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0):

Your data at the URL provided contains an object with a property named `category` whit the value being an array. This array is what I suspect you are expecting to parse.
So, only change the call ty myFunction from:

```
myFunction(myArr);
```

to:

```
myFunction(myArr.category);
```